# Django custom decorator user_passes_test() can it obtain url parameters?

Tags: python, django

Can Django's `user_passes_test()` access view parameters?

For example I have view that receives an `id` to retrieve specific record:

```
def property(request, id):
    property = Property.objects.get(id=int(id))
```

The record has a field named user_id that contains the id for user that originally created record. I want users to be able to view only their own records otherwise be redirected.

I'd like to use a custom decorator which seems simple and clean.

For custom decorator is there some variation of something like this that will work?

```
@user_passes_test(request.user.id = Property.objects.get(id=int(id)).id, login_url='/index/')
def property(request, id):
    property = Property.objects.get(id=int(id))
```

I have tried creating separate `test_func` named `user_is_property_owner` to contain logic to compare current user to property record user_id

```
@user_passes_test(user_is_property_owner(id), login_url='/index/')
def property(request, id):
    property = Property.objects.get(id=int(id))


def user_is_property_owner(property_id):
    is_owner = False
    try:
        Property.objects.filter(id=property_id, user_id=user_id).exists()
        is_owner = True
    except Property.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

But having trouble getting current user id and the property id from the request into the  `user_is_property_owner` decorator function.

---

EDIT to add solution I was using. I did test inside each view test was required. It is simple. i thought using a decorator might be prettier and slightly more simple.

```
def property(request, id):

    # get object 
    property = Property.objects.get(id=int(id))

    # test if request user is not user id on property record    
    if request.user.id != property.user_id:
        # user is not same as property user id so redirect to index
        return redirect('index')

    # rest of the code if request user is user_id on property record 
    # eg it is ok to let user into view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, (using class based views), I'll handle this in the `get_queryset` method so it would be something like

```
class PropertyDetail(DetailView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.property_set.all()
```

and that will give a 404 if the property isn't for the current user. You might prefer to use a project like [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) if you end up with more permission relationships than just `Property`.

If you take a look at [UserPassesTestMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c1aec0feda73ede09503192a66f973598aef901d/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py) you'll see that it processes the `test_func` before calling `dispatch` so you'll have to call `self.get_object(request)` yourself if you decide to go that route.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using class based views. So it looks like I am then limited to doing test and redirect inside each view where I want to restrict this.

Comment: It's fairly simple to switch to class based views. The advantage is that they can help isolate the "object getting" aspects of your code so if you have a dozen views that are all keyed off of a property, you can easily hook into either the `get_queryset` or `get_object` methods available.

If you're really stuck in function based views, then a decorator to encapsulate the object lookup isn't bad.

Comment: Comment editting and formatting is tough on SO, so maybe a decorator whose body returns `def inner(request, id): return func(request, self.request.user.property_set.get(pk=id))`

Comment: Thanks Alex. Def value in class based views. Would decorator look like this:  `@user_passes_test(inner(request, id), login_url='/index/')` ?